# React Native JS Synchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sqlite, async-await

I am writing a lyrics app, that saves a song book and the songs in that book to an SQL lite database. I am mapping through an array of books and calling an API to save the book's songs.
I want the saveBook() function to fully complete before moving on to the saveBookSong() function. I have tried async await but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks, Sam

```
useEffect( () => {
   Books.map ((book) =>{
    saveBook(book)
    saveBookSong(book.songId.toString())
  })
```

```
 function saveBook(book) {
   db.transaction( (tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `INSERT INTO books (id, description, img, name, song_id)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
        [book.id, book.description, book.img, book.name, book.songId],
        () => {
          console.log("Saved!!", book.id)
        }
    );
  });
}
```

```
 function saveBookSong(id) {
   axios
    .get(`songs/${id}`)
    .then((bookSong) => {
      bookSong.data.forEach((song) => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(
            `INSERT INTO songs (id, book, book_id, data, int_song_number, lang, search_title, song_number, title, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
            [
              song.id,
              song.book,
              song.bookId,
              song.data,
              song.intSongNumber,
              song.lang,
              song.searchTitle,
              song.songNumber,
              song.title,
              song.url,
            ],
            () => {
            }
          );
        });

      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want all the books to be saved in parallel. I would do this:

```
useEffect( () => {
    const bookSavings = Books.map(async (book) =>{
        await saveBook(book)
        await saveBookSong(book.songId.toString())
    });
    // If you want to wait for all books to be saved
    await Promise.all(bookSavings);
    // ... Whatever else you want to do in your useEffect
}, [Books])
```

Alright, but you can't simply `await` `saveBook` and `saveBookSong` because they are not `async` functions. Let's move forward.

Under the hood, async functions are just functions that return promises. We can actually `await` any promise. Therefore, you can make `saveBook` and `saveBookSong` awaitable by wrapping them in promises, like this:

```
function saveBook(book) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.transaction( (tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `INSERT INTO books (id, description, img, name, song_id)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
                [book.id, book.description, book.img, book.name, book.songId],
                () => {
                    console.log("Saved!!", book.id)
                    resolve(); // <- THIS IS IMPORTANT
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
The second function requires a bit extra caring because, like you pointed out, it contains a loop. However, that's not really different from the top-level `.map` function that you had. Here's my (untested) suggestion, hopefully you can work from here. I splitted the function in two, to make it more understandable:

```
async function saveBookSong(id) {
    const bookSong = await axios.get(`songs/${id}`);
    const savePromises = bookSong.data.map(song => {
        return saveSong(song);
    });
    await Promise.all(savePromises);
}

function saveSong(song) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `INSERT INTO songs (id, book, book_id, data, int_song_number, lang, search_title, song_number, title, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
                [
                    song.id,
                    song.book,
                    song.bookId,
                    song.data,
                    song.intSongNumber,
                    song.lang,
                    song.searchTitle,
                    song.songNumber,
                    song.title,
                    song.url,
                ],
                resolve
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken .map() is not async aware. So I would suggest two solutions to your problem:

1)

```
useEffect( () => {
   Books.map ((book) =>{
    saveBook(book).then(() => saveBookSong(book.songId.toString()))
  }, [Books])
```

In this case you go with then after first function is executed.

2)

```
useEffect( () => {
const manageBooks = async() => {
 for (book of Books) {
       await saveBook(book);
       await saveBookSong(book.songId.toString());
 }
}
      }, [Books])
```

You can go with async for loop which will wait for executing first task before moving to another one

Comment: Do I need to add async to saveBook,saveBookSong functions?

Comment: it has not fixed the bug :(